# Can a person tell if a plant was grown hydroponically or in a soil medium

Tags: hydroponic

The question is very simple, yet I can't seem to find the answer. Is there any identifying marks overall that someone can point out, to tell if a plant was grown hydroponically or not?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if there is a way to tell the difference, it has to be about the roots.

Answer (score 2):

I think an expert of a specific variety, with much experience (in your place) on hydroponics, green house and open field he could tell you the difference (not 100%, and with various plants).

Growth on soil (open field): it has very different conditions, so dry and wet; cold and hot; sun burns and parasites. In other words: a lot of stress (and for some vegetable it means better, most tasty).

Greenhouses reduces a lot of stresses, and let plants to growth quicker (so also less sign), so it would be more difficult.

But humans are very good on learning. I think if one persons sees every days different cultivations, after one months it could tell you what is the origin (by heart, probably without giving you solid characteristics).  This is not so different of recognising apple varieties (not just the 10 more common, but the 200, with then parents and the similar varieties of the more common kinds).

I'm more sure that chemical analysis could tell you without doubts the hydroponics.